# Xcode not showing full list of segues when ctrl + drag

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue

**Software Information:** Xcode Version 7.0.1 (7A1001)

**Goal:** I want to perform a `segue` between two *View Controllers* using a *`UIButton`*.

**Situation:** Normally when *CTRL + DRAG* from the *`UIButton`* to the second *View Controller* it appears a list of possible segues in two categories *Action Segues* and *Non-Adaptive Action Segues*.

**Problem:** When performing *CTRL + DRAG* the segues list showed is the following,

[Not Complete Segue List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qyh4.png)

**Question:** How can i get the full list of segues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of segues you are seeing are the ones available when you have *disabled Size Classes*.

To get back the full list, click the *Use Size Classes* box in the **Interface Builder Document** section in the *File Inspector*.

[image: Enable Size Classes]

Comment: Note that in newer versions of Xcode "Use Size Classes" is "Use Trait Variations".